# When I have Published my customization package to multiple tenant, Acumatica Bill of material Screens Entry not showing in site map table

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

When  I have Published my customization package to multiple tenant, Acumatica Bill of material Screens Entry not showing in site map table.

I have published package in two tenant comapnyid 2 and 3.

I execpt entry for Bill of material in site map show with company id 2 and 3.

But it is shwoing only with company id 1.

Please help

Comment: Can you double check if you have a Sitemap entry in your Customization Package?

Comment: Yes, I have site map entry in my customization package for my screens but I did not have site map entry for AM208000 (Acumatica Bill of material screen)

Comment: Also, once we have created multiple tenant,  is acumatica created all the acumatica screens entry in site map with tenant id.

Comment: Can you access AM208000 by manually entering the screen id to the url?
Does Manufacturing feature is enabled for both tenants?

Comment: yes i am able to access AM208000 by  manually entering the screen id. My issue is AM208000 screen entry not saving tenant wise in SiteMap table  of accumatica.

Comment: Try to add AM208000 sitemap entry to your customization project.